# 404 not found after cloning HTTP request in HTTP interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, http, .net-core

I am developing an Angular application and trying to resolve the IE caching issue.Web API is developed in .NET Core. From many articles, I found the issue can be resolved by adding no cache in the HTTP request header. Here's what I have

```
const clonedReq = req.clone({
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  })
});
```

But as soon as I use the above code, all API calls error out with 404 error.

Below is the captured HTTP requet in developer tools:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: cache-control
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:4900
Origin: http://localhost:6521
```

Comment: Did you use chrome dev tools to test the network calls? Just look in to network tab and check the request url

Comment: Yes url is completely fine. Without the interceptor everything was working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Get request without any auth token then open the url pasting url tab in browser and check if you are getting the result.

You could have one the following issue - 
1. API you requesting has wrong URL
2. Requested API is not implemented or not available.

Why are you using two headers in HTTP clone ?

```
const clonedReq = req.clone({
  headers: req.headers.set('Cache-Control','no-cache') . // Header 1
  headers: new HttpHeaders({                             // Header 2
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Pragma' : 'no-cache' //IE Ajax cache
  })
});
```

Comment: None of them is the case. I am able to get the response hitting the url directly.

Comment: why are you using 2 headers in clone method ? Answer updated.

Comment: It is working if you just remove `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'`

Comment: What is the reason, I still want IE to not cache api responses

Comment: Following this article https://medium.com/@tltjr/disabling-internet-explorer-caching-in-your-angular-5-application-3e148f4437ad

Comment: updated the answer with `'If-Modified-Since' : 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'`

Comment: update the answer with . `Pragma` option in header. It it doesn't work then you may need to reproduce this issue in https://stackblitz.com get this fixed.